# TYPO3 with TemplaVoila missing Backend Content View

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

After setting up TemplaVoila like ever i end up in this view.

[image: Page view with Templa Voila]

I set up TV with the wizard. all example pages and content elements were there (i deleted them after)
but they werent visible in Page view. also there are no "new contentelement" icons and all that stuff.

Heres the typoscript:

```
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page.10 = USER
page.10.userFunc = tx_templavoila_pi1->main_page
```

No errors, installed everything like 20 times before. Just another TYPO3 Version 4.6.3 - but theres nothing to if there are some conflicts with TV and TYPO3 4.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your TemplaVoila mapping. This usually happens when you don't have an entity for content elements mapped.